# Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: orm, telerik

Has anyone used this ORM?

[Telerik OpenAccess](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx)

Critiques/Praise? I work in an office that is heavily invested in other telerik venues and I would like to know more about their newest product and whether or not it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm testing it, the free Express version.

**Pros**

- Performance (caching, lazy load etc. out of the box)
- Easy integration
- Great VS.NET integration, wizards
- Cool community

**Cons**

- Missing real distributed architecture support and patterns
- Wizards hide configuration files and sometimes you must fix thing with hand
- SQL CE support still missing

Chris is right, but Entity Framework works like beta, and OA has LINQ support too.

Comment: OA and LINQ support! most of the methods are marked depreciated... I've had enough of OA

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think .net's Linq and it's entity framework are the best since sliced bread.  I also use telerik a lot and look into everything that they make but ORM doesn't compare to M$ .NET Linq.

Chris